# Mimic or emulate a passive RFID tag and program it

Tags: android, nfc, hardware, rfid

I have a device that contains an RFID reader/writer supporting ISO/IEC 14443 (13.56 MHz frequency). It works with MiFARE, NTag215 tags. I want to automate the testing without having to physically present the tags to the device.

I'm wondering if there's Off The Shelf (OTS) hardware that can mimic a passive RFID tag and can be programmed via a software API?  Ideally I would like automate a test in two steps (a) program a tag and (b) present the tag to the device.

There's plenty of readers/writers with USB and Bluetooth interfaces and software APIs but these are only for programming or reading tags.

A related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610478/android-application-to-mimic-a-physical-rfid-card) was if it's possible to have an android application mimic a physical card.  My question is somewhat similar but more generic and not just for Android phones. My preference is to buy something OTS rather than build something, e.g. with an Arduino type device.

Comment: To the moderators, this is related to programming tools which allows me to test my software without manual interaction.  The answer referred to me to a solution which includes an SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [Emutag](http://www.emutag.com/) should be able to serve your needs.
NTAG 215 is a higher memory version of NTAG 213.