# Native RFID detection on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, rfid

Is it possible for the current generation of iOS Devices to detect RFID signals natively without the need for external tech?

If it is not possible, what solutions exist that can allow the current generation of iPads and iPhones to detect RFID signals?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081926/reading-rfid-with-android-phones/13295210#13295210

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible, since no iOS device today has a RFID reader.

A solution is this: http://www.tsl.uk.com/products/1128-bluetooth-handheld-uhf-rfid-reader/